# RoR on Heroku: Why would ModelOne.count not work in ModelTwo only in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My own computer: MacOS

Production: Heroku

App: RoR with MySQL database (setup correctly both locally and in production)

ModelTwo `has_many` ModelOne

ModelOne `belongs_to` ModelTwo

ModelTwo uses `self.model_one.any?` to make a decision

This works fine, 100% ok, in development and test (RSpec) environments.

In production (Heroku), `self.model_one.any?` always returns `false`.

Doing `heroku run rails c` everything runs smoothly. I can see the records, make the EXACT SAME CALLS AS MY CODE (literally cmd+c cmd+v from Atom to console), and it all works like it should. I get `true` when it should be `true` and `false` when it should be `false`.

The app doesn't crash, because it's not a critical decision, but it does end up using a more performance-demanding block, which is exactly what I'm hoping to avoid by creating this conditional.

I've been trying to figure this out for a while, so one of the things I did do is put `puts` statements all over the place, to track each change/save to ModelOne and also how ModelTwo is getting data at each point.

It turns out, ModelTwo seems blind to ModelOne completely. Not only does `self.model_one.any?` always return `false`, but also `ModelOne.count` always return `0`. Even when `rails c` reads it correctly and other Models and Controllers in the app do, too!

Again, this is ONLY happening in Heroku production.

Development is 100% ok! I know from watching `rails s` as I navigate the app. All of my `puts` statements show data and Models working as they should.

Tests are 100% ok! I made sure my RSpec ModelTwo test was testing THIS decision specifically and it passes!

WHAT IS GOING ON?? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Rails have different environments. And different database for each environment. If you have records in development or production db, they are not present in test db.
So `rails c` could give a different result.
It is hard to analyze without code examples, but I assume you have validation errors please check `model_one_entity.errors`.

I would assume issues in controller strong parameters, but if you have `ModelOne.count` zero, then it does not create it at all, so you need to check validations. Or use `create!` and `save!` methods instead of `create` and `save`

Comment: Well, that's the thing. I run `rails c` in production and see things happening as they should. Records are created in production. Other Models see them and interact accordingly. It's only this specific Model. `heroku logs` shows me the records being created, other Models and Controllers getting to it, getting `.count` correct. It's this specific thing. I'll add code.

Comment: So, I just ran test, development, and production again, because I wanted to post the code, and also all of the log output of each environment. Doing that, I noticed that test logs do show the same problem. The tests pass, but the logs show that the app is going through the less desired code block after all. I guess test performance is not affected enough for me to notice, since it has almost no data.

Comment: Anyways, in all of that, I noticed I was calling the method in ModelTwo from a `.first_or_initialize` block and then it dawned on me that maybe that's not "concrete" enough for Rails to go and run things fully. I changed the method call to a variable outside the `.first_or_initialize` block and sure enough, now it works! In all environments.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I feel silly. And like I need to refactor these tests to actually catch this!